# How to set a default webapp in jetty Docker

Tags: docker, jetty

Is there a way to set in the Dockerfile of jetty the default webapp?

The doc says, you can rename you webapp.war as root.war, but if don't want to do that, is there a way to specify the webapp as you default (and only) webapp. 
Do I have to modify the Dockerfile or can I specify in the webapp (context.xml)

Thanks, Rajesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create a jetty config file under project/WEB-INF, you can also see it http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-specific-webapp-deployment.html#deployable-descriptor-file

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want to access webapp.war by using `<hostname:port>` with out the web app name..
you can do redirection by using root/index.html  which redirects to your web app..
content of index.html would be

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=/<your Web app name>/"/> 
</head>
<body>
</body>
```